# how do you count numbers in a single string in c#

Tags: c#

So i was trying to print 1000 didgits of pi and every 6 there would be counted up and print the final number of how many 6-es there are i know how to do it with arrays but not a single string

Comment: Multiple ways use regex or simple `char.IsDigit()` to filter out numbers

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the solution you are searching for:

```
var sum = 0;
foreach (char s in string)
{
    if (s == '6')
    {
        sum += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: also i see this alot but what is a var?

Comment: It is a variable without a specific datatype so it can be anything.

Comment: also if i wanted a number like 20 how would i implement that ?

Comment: The loop I have just built checks every character but 20 are two characters: '2' & '0". So what you have to do is check if the current character is '2' and if the next character is '0'.

Comment: I think this is what you are searching for try this: **for (int i = 0; i < string.Length; i++) { if (string[i] == '2' && string[i+1] == '0') { sum += 1; }  }**

Comment: sorry i am kind of new to coding but how would i do that?

Comment: read the comment above yours I gave you the code you just have to switch string with your variable name and create a sum variable.

Comment: No problem! Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var sixcount = 0;
for (char c in piString) {
  if (c == '6') sixcount++;
}
```

There's probably a slick LINQ equivalent too.

It's easy to iterate over the characters of strings.

Comment: The linq you're looking for is probably `piString.Count(c => c == '6')`

Answer (score 1):

var result = `piString.Count(x => x == '6')`

This Linq code shall help

`String` is internally a `char[]`, so we can use Linq `Count` with predicate to get the exact result